# Tensorflow custom gradient not giving expected answer

Tags: python, tensorflow, automatic-differentiation

I am learning custom gradient in Tensorflow 1.14. I am testing it out by defining custom gradient for a simple ReLu function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 

@tf.custom_gradient
def rateFunction(v_):
    z_ = tf.nn.relu(v_)

    def grad(dy):
        dz_dv = tf.where(tf.greater(v_, 0.), tf.ones_like(v_), tf.zeros_like(v_))

        dv = dy * dz_dv

        return [dv]

    return z_, grad

# define test input 
vv = tf.random.normal((32,100))

# output from customized gradient
z1 = rateFunction(vv)
```

and I expect the gradient computed using the custom gradient to match the gradient of the actual ReLU, but it does not:

```
# output of actual relu
z2 = tf.nn.relu(vv)

# Compute the gradient
sess = tf.Session()
dzdv1=sess.run(tf.gradients(z1, vv)[0])
dzdv2=sess.run(tf.gradients(z2, vv)[0])

# Expect to match, i.e. difference to be 0
print(np.mean(np.abs(dzdv1-dzdv2)))
```

but the difference between the expected and actual is not zero. I got an mean absolute difference of about 0.49. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from

```
vv = tf.random.normal((32,100))
```

a different input is generated each time.